# Jquery twenty twenty plugin with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Created a twenty twenty before after. but I want this before after inside the jquery slider. So that i can view group images of before after

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Stylish-jQuery-Images-Comparison-Plugin-twentytwenty/css/twentytwenty.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Stylish-jQuery-Images-Comparison-Plugin-twentytwenty/js/jquery.twentytwenty.js"></script>
<script src="http://stephband.info/jquery.event.move/js/jquery.event.move.js"></script>

<div id="container1">
  <img src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/29/sample-before.png">
  <img src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/28/sample-after.png">
</div>
```

Please help me to create this.

Comment: Hello, what slider are you trying to implement ?

Comment: Any slider , I just want to view display Group of before after with net previous button  @GrégoireHertault

Comment: I have to say I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to put the entire thing into a slider (as to have multiple before/after examples) or do you want to do something else entirely? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes!! I want to put the entire thing into a slider (as to have multiple before/after examples) @herrbischoff

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite straight forward. I have put together a working example for you, enjoy:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //initialize swiper when document ready  
  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    onInit: function() {
      $(".swiper-slide-active .container").twentytwenty();
    },
    onSlideChangeStart: function() {
      $('.swiper-slide-active .container').twentytwenty();
    },
    onlyExternal: true
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Stylish-jQuery-Images-Comparison-Plugin-twentytwenty/css/twentytwenty.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.0.7/css/swiper.min.css">

  <div class="swiper-container">

    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/29/sample-before.png">
          <img src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/28/sample-after.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/conan_bef_sm.jpg">
          <img src="http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/conan_aft_sm.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.0.7/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Stylish-jQuery-Images-Comparison-Plugin-twentytwenty/js/jquery.twentytwenty.js"></script>
  <script src="http://stephband.info/jquery.event.move/js/jquery.event.move.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swiper Slider I tried to use herrbischoff's method, but was unsuccessful I think due to some outdated swiper data. My solution is below and notice a few changes:

- `touchRatio: 0` is used to turn off dragging so they can actually use the twentytwenty slider.
- `navigation`, `pagination` need to be used as objects
- `on: { ... }` followed by subobjects of the event name is the new way to access events.
- `onSlideChangeStart` doesn't exist in the new API data, `slideChangeTransitionStart` does so I believe it was renamed.

(This is only the script solution, you must add the appropriate html and pull in and js and css to get this to function properly)

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready  
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        touchRatio: 0,

        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },

        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            type: 'bullets',
        },

        on: {
            init: function () {
                jQuery(".swiper-slide-active .swiper-container").twentytwenty();
            },
            slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
                jQuery('.swiper-slide-active .swiper-container').twentytwenty();
            },
        },
    });
});
</script>
```